# Symfony 3 + JMSI18nRoutingBundle set locale

Tags: symfony

I have a problem setting a locale. I have Fos user bundle + JMSI18nRoutingBundle set up properly .

For example when i go for url : domain/login my default locale is set up properly . For the url domain/fr/login also everything is ok .

I have tried to set up http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

How can change the language by Clicking on the link for the aplication. Does i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand full of your problem, but i'm using this in my twig to switch between languages. You can modify it to simple anchor links

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" class="form-control">
    <option>{{ 'Language'|trans }}</option>
    <option value="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'it'})) }}">{{ 'Italian'|trans }}</option>
    <option value="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">{{ 'English'|trans }}</option>
    <option value="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}">{{ 'French'|trans }}</option>
    <option value="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'es'})) }}">{{ 'Spanish'|trans }}</option>
    <option value="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'pt'})) }}">{{ 'Portuguese'|trans }}</option>
    <option value="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'de'})) }}">{{ 'German'|trans }}</option>
</select>
```